# Call method from non-Activity class in Android

Tags: java, android, call

I have a Popup window (non-Activity class) that have some buttons. one of them (btn_audio), play or pause sound and it works like a charm.
Now I want to call two method, `play()` and `pause()` in my HomeActivity and inside of `onStop()` method in all of my Activities. it doesn't work, call `play()` and `pause()` in other Activity's occur NullPointException.

```
public class Popup_Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  Button btn_audio;
  public static MediaPlayer player;     String play_or_pause;
  int num_ply, tim_pos; int [] resID;// Audio
  SharedPreferences sp;
void showPopup(final Activity context) {

  this.context=context;
  LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout_menu, viewGroup);
  sp = context.getSharedPreferences("text", MODE_PRIVATE);
       btn_audio = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_audio);    // audio
        layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_audio).setOnClickListener(this);


        @Override
        public void onClick(View whichButtonIsClicked) {
  switch (whichButtonIsClicked.getId())  {
  case R.id.btn_audio:                      
    if (play_or_pause.equals("play")) { 
      pause();
  } else {
      play(context);
  }
  sp.edit().putString("play_or_pause", play_or_pause).commit();   // save current stat
}   ////// close of showPopup()

          //define play and pause methods   
public void pause() {
  player.pause();
  btn_audio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_audio_pause);
  play_or_pause="pause"; // current state is 'pause'
            }

public void play(final Context context) {
  if(num_ply==9){num_ply=0; }
  resID = new int []{ R.raw.tarane,R.raw.toofan,R.raw.shane,R.raw.kharazmi,R.raw.golhaye_khofte,R.raw.rang,R.raw.naghmeh,R.raw.dar_rahe_to,R.raw.emperor};
  player=MediaPlayer.create(context,resID[num_ply]);
  player.seekTo(tim_pos);           
  player.start();
  btn_audio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_audio_play);
  play_or_pause="play";      // current state is 'play'
  player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
  tim_pos=0;            num_ply++;      play(context);
          }
      });
  } 
 }
```

and my HomeActivity :

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 Popup_Menu ppp;
 @Override
protected void onCreate..............
 ppp = new Popup_Menu();
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("text", MODE_PRIVATE);

 if(sp.getString("play_or_pause", "play").equals("pause")){
   ppp.play(getApplicationContext());                 // ERROR
    }    // audio

}  /// close of onCreate

@Override
public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();                               
  if(play_or_pause.equals("play")){
  ppp.tim_pos= ppp.player.getCurrentP
```

Ok, I decided to use service to resolve this problem and it works well for play(). but when playing, still i can't call pause() method from SoundService because player object is null. I think by creating an object, from SoundService class, (ss in Popup_Menu class) , default constructor put player value to null (when playing and player object wasn't null). and calling player.pause occur error.
How PLEASE can i pause this one_week_friend!!!

```
public class SoundService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer player;     int num_ply, tim_pos;   int [] resID;


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    resID = new int []{ R.raw.tarane,R.raw.toofan,R.raw.shane,R.raw.kharazmi,
            R.raw.golhaye_khofte,R.raw.rang,R.raw.naghmeh,R.raw.dar_rahe_to,R.raw.emperor     };
        player=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID[num_ply]);

        play();
        return Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY;
 }

public void play() {
    if(num_ply==9){num_ply=0; }
    player.seekTo(tim_pos);         
    player.start();
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {         
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
        tim_pos=0;          num_ply++;      play();
    }
    });
}

    public void resume(){
    player.seekTo(tim_pos);         
    player.start();
}

public void pause() {
    tim_pos= player.getCurrentPosition();          ////// ERROR
    player.pause();          ////// ERROR
    num_ply++;
}


public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }
}
```

And my Popup_Menu class:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View whichButtonIsClicked) {
    switch (whichButtonIsClicked.getId())  {

    case R.id.btn_audio:
    if (play_or_pause.equals("play")) {
        btn_audio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_audio_pause);
        play_or_pause="pause";       // current state is 'pause'
        SoundService ss = new SoundService();
        ss.pause();          ////// ERROR
    } else {
        btn_audio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_audio_play);
        play_or_pause="play";        // current state is 'play'
        Intent sound_Intent = new Intent(context , SoundService.class);     // start service
        context.startService(sound_Intent);
    }
        sp.edit().putString("play_or_pause", play_or_pause).commit();   // save current state
    break;
```

LogCat:

```
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at com.codegostarNiloo.negar.SoundService.pause(SoundService.java:47)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at com.codegostarNiloo.negar.Popup_Menu.onClick(Popup_Menu.java:234)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4209)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17457)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
08-05 01:03:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(25356):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 01:03:32.066: D/dalvikvm(25356): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x5f1c9000
```

Comment: can you include your stack trace?

Comment: Please indent you code, it's hard to read

Comment: post your logcat messages

Comment: Please stop this right away, do not store activity references in fields of other activities in attempt to control them

Comment: Non Activity? No you don't... `Popup_Menu extends Activity`

Comment: You are "manually" instantiating an activity. Activities are not meant to be used like that. I am sure there are many things not set up due to that which make your app crash.

Comment: You never called `showPopup`. Of course things are null.

Comment: You should use `service`

Comment: @  Tim Castelijns , please tell me why? I need object of Popup_Menu class to access it's methods, play() and pause().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah...!!! Done. It now working.it doesn't need to create new object. I must change modifire of (object)player and pause() methode and everything in it, to STATIC. So righte now i can access all objects and variables.
Thanks cricket_007...

Answer (score 2):

First, off, don't extend an Activity if it's a non Activity, as you claim, then passing a Context is preferred over an Activity

Secondly, there is a class called DialogFragment that is intended to be used as a popup dialog

I think you are looking for something like the following, though

```
public class Popup_Menu implements OnClickListener {
    Button btn_audio;
    public MediaPlayer player;     
    String play_or_pause;
    int num_ply, tim_pos; 
    int [] resID;// Audio
    SharedPreferences sp;
    Context context ;

    public Popup_Menu(final Context context) {

        this.context= context;
        sp = this.context.getSharedPreferences("text", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

       // LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout)  view.findViewById(R.id.popup);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout_menu, viewGroup);
        btn_audio = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_audio);    // audio
        btn_audio.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

You can now create a `new Popup_Menu(HomeActivity.this)`

Comment: The exact same? Nullpointer in `Popup_Menu.play`? Then I suggest you set some breakpoints and see what is null

Comment: Notice that I have not initialized `player`, `play_or_pause`, etc... Those are of course going to be null if you just copied this exactly

Comment: dear cricket_007, I passed context to Popup_Menu class and invented it's constracture like your code and still not working and gives same Exception without music playing. but my code played music in HomeActivity and then crashed. Adding above, I extended my Popup_Menu from Activity why "MODE_PRIVATE" of SharedPreferences caused (cannot resolved to a variable) Error. this Menu must be prepered in All Activity's not only HomeActivity and it's own btn_audio must control music wherever.

Comment: You need to statically import `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`... You should not extend Activity if this is not actually an Activity

Comment: Also, though, it sounds like you really want some Fragment class if you want it to be in all Activities and have its own layout functions

Comment: Ok, Context.MODE_PRIVATE resolved ! but force closed again with Nullpointer  in HomeActivity like LogCat. No, I initialized player, play_or_pause, etc correctly. So, you suggest using dialog fragment for my purpose?  something like this:       http://uupload.ir/files/14b4_guide_sett.png     this is my popup window ...

Comment: I'm not sure what is null since I can't see line numbers in your code. Dialogs are "popup windows", yes. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html  I don't know what your picture is showing. If you want a "clickable audio icon" view in any Activity, you actually want a View class. https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: thank you dear cricket_007 for your helps. I checked out these two links and i was confused more. According this: uupload.ir/files/14b4_guide_sett.png, I need a menu maked from linear layout that contain buttons, seekbars, Textview, checkbox and ext... and everything works like a charm. I only wish to can create one object from popup_menu and using it in my Home Activity class. I think i have made your time, busy with my problem. if it isn't my cheeky, as my last hope, can i send you an email contain complete of my two class and manifest and xml and ext.. ?

Comment: A `new Popup_Menu(HomeActivity.this)` is one object. A Fragment or a custom view are also only one object and they inflate custom layouts just like you want... It's up to you to find which works best for your code, and I'm not in a position to share my email. Feel free to create more questions on Stackoverflow and see about a [mcve]

Comment: new Popup_Menu(HomeActivity.this) doesn't work, I dont need custom view and I never have succeed to make simple object...  OK, thanks for your help... I try to do my purpose with service !